# Blackberry issue on cell site GPS tracking

Tags: blackberry, gps

In my BB app, I try to fetch the location using the cell site.

But it always throws a Location exception:

```
Timed out while waiting for Geolocation.m=0
```

Here is my code

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
criteria.setPreferredPowerConsumption(Criteria.POWER_USAGE_LOW);
LocationProvider provider = LocationProvider.getInstance(criteria);
Location location = provider.getLocation(-1);
QualifiedCoordinates qualifiedCoordinates = location.getQualifiedCoordinates();
double latitude = qualifiedCoordinates.getLatitude();
double longitude = qualifiedCoordinates.getLongitude();
```

But if i change the parameters to

```
criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(50);
criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(50);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
criteria.setPreferredPowerConsumption(Criteria.POWER_USAGE_HIGH);
```

the assisted GPS works fine and I will get the correct location of device.

Comment: I found Criteria.POWER_USAGE_LOW worked fine in the app I was developing a couple of weeks ago, but hasn't been working (in the Sim or on the Device since) 'the big crash'. Could it be that a part of the BB service isn't working correctly or has been disabled?

Answer (score 0):

```
class LocationTracker{
private LocationProvider provider;
Criteria cr;
public LocationTracker() {
    cr= new Criteria();
    resetGPS();
}

public void resetGPS(){       
        try {
            provider = LocationProvider.getInstance(cr);
            if(provider != null) {
                    provider.setLocationListener(new MyLocationListener(),60, -1, -1);
            }
        }
        catch (LocationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }     
    }
}

class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
public void locationUpdated(LocationProvider provider, Location location){
    if(location != null && location.isValid()){               
        QualifiedCoordinates qc = location.getQualifiedCoordinates();
        try {
            LAT = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude();
            System.out.println("=============================lattitude :: "+LAT);
            LONG= location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude();
            System.out.println("==================================longitude ::"+LONG);

        } 
        catch(Exception e){ 
           }
    }
}

public void providerStateChanged(LocationProvider provider, int newState){
     if(newState == LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE){
            provider.reset();
            provider.setLocationListener(null, 0, 0, -1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried the same code which i tried earlier and now it is working perfectly..!!!    
Anyway thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Like vijay, you can register to location update.

If you still want to use your solution, you have to be sure that
- It is threaded (and not just only not to get an ANR, it is a requirement)
- You have a SIM card with a Blackberry option
- You run on at least OS 5.0.0